# Need help for regular expression for percent value

Tags: regex

I am trying to pass value as 95%

```
numexu = 95%
"^((>|GT|>=|GE|<|LT|<=|LE|==|EQ|!=|NE)?\\s*\\d?[%]?)$
 if (!regex.IsMatch(numexu))
            throw new ArgumentException("Percent expression is in an invalid format.");
```

it is throwing exception in code.

Regards,
Regex

Comment: ^((>|GT|>=|GE|<|LT|<=|LE|==|EQ|!=|NE)?\s*\d?[\%]?)$  try this

Comment: Could you please assess language (python, perl, java?) and check your presentation (indentation)

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell us the language and paste the part of the code that is interesting formatted well.

Comment: thanks moon but this one is not working

Answer (score 2):

You are checking only for 1 number `\\d?`, try instead this: `\\d{0,2}`, this accepts 0, 1 or 2 numbers. The `?` makes it 0 or 1 times matching.

I am not sure if you need to escape the `%`, if so then `\\%`. Additionally if you have only one character you can skip the brackets `[%]`, so `%` (or `\\%`, if needed to escape)

Answer (score 0):

```
   This Function will work for your requirement 

 function check() {
     var txtfield; txtfield =document.getElementById('txtbox').value; 
     var reg=/^(\d{0,2}%?$)/;
     if(reg.test(txtfield)){
     alert("match");

     }
     else { alert("Try again"); } 
      }
```